# Bug in rep from specific questions on user popup

Tags: support, reputation

If you look at the reps from the question, it should be 5*5 -2 * 1 = 23
But if you look at the rep from the question on the user popup, its -(5*5 + 2*1) = -27.
Is this a bug, or something I am missing?

[image: SO Rep calculation on popup]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is correct.

The top of the notification popup line tells you the reputation changes for today, this week and this month. Today someone downvoted your post and you got -2 from that.

At the bottom of the notification popup you see the total reputation for every single question which is -27 for that particulary question because of upvotes, downvotes and a bounty you set on that question.

```
-50 + 25 - 2 = -27
           ^------ 1 downvote
       ^----- 5 upvotes
 ^---- bounty
```